# View available in shared folder

Tags: windows-8, storage, shared-folders, windows-server

I have access to a shared folder on a Windows Server. I have no access to that server other than this shared folder, I don't even know the windows version. I also don't know if there is any storage quota configured specifically for that shared folder or if whole partition storage is available.

In desktop I have Windows 8.

How can I view its total, used and available storage?

Comment: How are you accessing this share at the moment? If you map the share to a drive letter then check in Windows Explorer (My Computer) it should show you some details however depending on the setup these can be misleading...

Comment: Ask your server administrator.

Comment: Thanks Charles, if you can add your answer below I'll plus you.